# Why is IF/ELSE statement Not working properly?

Tags: c#, selenium, if-statement, case

I need some assistance please... I am having problems with the ELSE statement, the code executes whatever that is in the IF bracket but never reach the ELSE bracket. It works without issues with Chrome but fail every time with IE. This is my code:

```
IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.00));
IList<IWebElement> boxList = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("ListBox option"));

bool textExists = false;

foreach (var option in boxList)
{
    if (option.Text.Equals("TEST"))
    {
        textExists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!textExists)
{
    _driver.FindElement(By.Id("AddButton")).Click();

    var newRecordInfo = table.CreateSet<FeatureInfo>();

    foreach (var recordData in newRecordInfo)
    {
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("DescTextBox")).SendKeys(recordData._discription);
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("PaTextBox")).SendKeys(recordData._score);

        new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("DropDown"))).SelectByValue("1");
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("SaveButton")).Click();
    }
}
else 
{
    SelectElement Select = new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("ListBox")));
    Select.SelectByText("TEST");

    _driver.FindElement(By.Id("DeleteButton")).Click();

    IAlert alert = _driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    alert.Accept();

    //IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
    //js.ExecuteScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);


}
```

Here is the HTML:

IE

```
<div class="section-container">
    <div class="section">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:52%" valign="top">
                    <h5 class="section-label">Active Values</h5>
                    <div class="section">
                        <select size="10" name="DescTextBox" id="DescTextBox" onclick="ListBox_Click()" style="width:98%;display:block;margin-bottom:10px">
    <option value="14" UseCount="0" PassingScore="50" FirearmType="1">123ABC</option>
<option value="10" UseCount="0" PassingScore="170" FirearmType="2">BRTP</option>
<option value="9" UseCount="0" PassingScore="0" FirearmType="1">CORE TRAINING ELEMENTS</option>
<option value="12" UseCount="0" PassingScore="0" FirearmType="1">FAM (T&amp;E PISTOL)</option>
<option value="5" UseCount="559" PassingScore="0" FirearmType="2">FAM ONLY (RIFLE)</option>
<option value="1" UseCount="31" PassingScore="225" FirearmType="1">FLETC PPC (NON-CITP)</option>
<option value="2" UseCount="4001" PassingScore="225" FirearmType="1">HHS-OIG PQC</option>
<option value="3" UseCount="603" PassingScore="240" FirearmType="2">HHS-OIG RQC</option>
<option value="6" UseCount="5" PassingScore="0" FirearmType="1">OTHER FEDERAL AGENCIES-PISTOL</option>
<option value="7" UseCount="2" PassingScore="0" FirearmType="2">OTHER FEDERAL AGENCIES-RIFLE</option>
<option value="11" UseCount="0" PassingScore="0" FirearmType="2">RCTP</option>
<option value="16" UseCount="0" PassingScore="50" FirearmType="1">TEST</option>
<option value="15" UseCount="0" PassingScore="50" FirearmType="1">TEXT_DELETE</option>

</select>
```

CHOME

```html
<div class="section-container">
  <div class="section">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
     <td style="width:52%" valign="top">
      <h5 class="section-label">Active Values</h5>
      <div class="section">
       <select size="10" name="DescTextBox" id="DescTextBox" onclick="ListBox_Click()" style="width:98%;display:block;margin-bottom:10px">
  <option value="14" UseCount="0" PassingScore="50" FirearmType="1">123ABC</option>
  <option value="10" UseCount="0" PassingScore="170" FirearmType="2">TRAINING</option>
  <option value="9" UseCount="0" PassingScore="0" FirearmType="1">TRAINING TWO</option>
  <option value="12" UseCount="0" PassingScore="0" FirearmType="1">TRAINING THREE</option>
  <option value="5" UseCount="559" PassingScore="0" FirearmType="2">TRAINING FOUR</option>
  <option value="1" UseCount="31" PassingScore="225" FirearmType="1">TRAINING FIVE</option>
  <option value="16" UseCount="0" PassingScore="50" FirearmType="1">TEST</option>
  <option value="15" UseCount="0" PassingScore="50" FirearmType="1">TEXT_DELETE</option>
```

Updated the post to add the HTML for IE and Chrome

Comment: what does `option.Text` equal for the time you expect it to exist?

Comment: maybe option.Text.Equals needs to use case insensitive

Comment: or there is whitespace...

Comment: @DanielA.White it is not constant. the idea is for the code to check if the TEXT is present.

Comment: @urlreader nope, I have even tried CONTAINS, it still execute only the IF and does not reach the ELSE

Comment: [Use your debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to see why `option.Text.Equals("TEST")` is always `false`.

Comment: _"Unreachable code detected"_ is a compile time rror, has nothing to do with your data or debugging. Post any  error messages you get, verbatim. Or change the title here.

Comment: @DanielA.White No Whitespace

Comment: @HenkHolterman It doesn't throw any errors or give an error message. It just only executes whatever that is in the IF statement and always ignores the ELSE

Comment: Then fix the title. And provide a sample of values in boxList.

Comment: @HenkHolterman OK, I have updated the title

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have included the values

Comment: Most likely the list is always empty, check if `CssSelector("ListBox option")` is correct. I don't know Selenium but I would expect `CssSelector("#ListBox option")` of `CssSelector("select option")`

Comment: @HenkHolterman tried ("#ListBox option") and ("select#ListBox option"), the same result

Comment: Look at the HTML in IE... is it exactly the same as in Chrome? Something about them is different me thinks...

Answer (score 1):

Try an alternate method of examining the OPTIONs. I moved some things around a little and simplified the code. I pulled the `SelectElement` up to the top and used it to loop through the options and filtered them using LINQ to see if any of them equal "TEST". I built a custom page with a `SELECT` and it executes through the `if` and `else` correctly.

```
public void Test()
{
    IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.00));
    SelectElement Select = new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("ListBox")));

    if (!Select.Options.Where(e => e.Text == "TEST").Any())
    {
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("AddButton")).Click();
        var newRecordInfo = table.CreateSet<FeatureInfo>();

        foreach (var recordData in newRecordInfo)
        {
            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("DescTextBox")).SendKeys(recordData._discription);
            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("PaTextBox")).SendKeys(recordData._score);

            new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("DropDown"))).SelectByValue("1");
            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("SaveButton")).Click();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Select.SelectByText("TEST");
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("DeleteButton")).Click();
        _driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `.Any()` is an improvement,but just cosmetic. `FindElement(By.Id())` is the proposed slution.

Comment: Hi, sorry it took me longer to respond to this. But I get the same error with the solution above. I compared the HTML from IE and Chrome, I don't see any major difference, I added the HTML for both in my original post.

Answer (score -1):

You're checking the object Text instead of checking the option variable

Use `option == "TEXT"` instead of `option.Text.Equals("TEST")`

Comment: Thanks for your response, it says "Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type 'IWebElement' and 'Sting'"

Comment: I think he meant to say `option.text == "TEXT"`... he forgot the `.text`. It won't make any difference but I think that's what he meant...